# Remove Ubuntu From Live USB

Tags: usb, uninstall

I want to use Ubuntu on my USB Stick as [shown here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

But I was wondering if I could restore my USB Stick after I've finished trying Ubuntu?

And if so, how?

Comment: You can simply format the USB again.

Comment: A maybe useful note: Trying to format the flash drive with Disks or GParted, I had the problem that my flash drive became "read only", but only for my user/computer. Surprisingly, a reboot solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these instructions:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/

---

Alternatively, if you're in a Windows machine you can also use `diskpart`:

Launch `diskpart` through Run ( <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ) or `cmd.exe`, then enter the following, line by line:

```
list disk    
select disk <insert disk number here>
clean
create partition primary
select part 1
format fs=ntfs label=<insert custom name here> quick
assign letter <insert custom single-letter here>
```

Comment: The [first link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/) worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 in 2019.  I really ought to grab the page's commands and put them into the answer, but apparently that page hasn't changed since [2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20090117033206/https://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/)

Comment: Would be helpful to know if anyone on Windows followed the `diskpart` instructions and whether they have bugs

Comment: @frank I followed them and came across no bugs https://i.imgur.com/uX4YtNp.png

Comment: @Nathan This did not work for me despite multiple attempts.

Comment: @NelsonGon hope you at least upvoted the solution that did work.  Would be good to post it here, too

Comment: @Nathan, I unfortunately don't remember how I fixed it but since I wanted to remove Ubuntu and put Mint instead, I just made a new live USB using UUI.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `change it back to a regular USB pen drive to keep your files`?

If so, the answer is `Yes, you can`; you can just format the USB.

- From Ubuntu: Use `Gparted` and give it whatever format you'd like.
- From Windows: The same thing, right-click on the USB drive and select the format.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Im going to intall it to my USB now.